# postgres \c with linebreaks

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm creating an export to csv that's a rather long query, as such, I placed the \copy command in a new file. The problem is that the newlines seem to break my command, is there a way I'm able to execute this command with line breaks?

For example:

```
\copy (select
        field1
        , field2
    FROM table
) to '/tmp/out.csv' csv;
```

I'm currently running that command from a sql file as such:

```
psql -f tocsv.sql
```

I don't think it matters that I'm running it from a file. Is there a way to execute the copy command with the line breaks in my query? I'd like to keep them there for legibility.

Comment: tr -d '\n' < tocsv.sql | psql

Answer (score 1):

From here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-psql.html) in `\copy` section:

> Tip

> Another way to obtain the same result as \copy ... to is to use the SQL COPY ... TO STDOUT command and terminate it with \g filename or \g |program. Unlike \copy, this method allows the command to span multiple lines; also, variable interpolation and backquote expansion can be used.